# How to see solution explorer in vs 2013 community edition while MVC app is running

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have an MVC4 application that I am working on in vs2013 community edition.

As with normal MVC development, while the application is running, it is usually possible to switch back to vs and access the solution explorer to modify views.

But when I try this in vs 2013 community edition, solution explorer is not visible.

I've looked in Tools Options but don't see any options related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in VS2013 Community Edition this is possible. 
[image]
When you start running your MVC4 app your IDE is changed to debugging view. In this view the Solution Explorer is not always shown.

You can enable the solution explorer (and many other windows) via the View menu.
[image]